# How can get the results of a CASE statement converted to TimeStamp to reflect as Date mm/dd/yyyy in SSRS / RDL

Tags: date, reporting-services, casting, timestamp, case

I have utilized a CASE statement as shown below, because I need to subtract five hours from the timestamp that is provided (which is in string format):

```
CASE
    when xxx <>'Original'
    then cast(substr(yyy,1,23) as timestamp) - interval '5' hour
    else ''
    end as result
```

The query runs find and produces a timestamp. When I put the full query into my RDL file to create my report in SSRS and change the Text Box Properties to the Data format mm/dd/yyyy and run the report, it continues to bring back the full TimeStamp.

*Note that I have utilized this same CAST outside of a CASE statement in the same query and when I update the Text Box Properties, it does as I would expect, and brings back a result of the date mm/dd/yyyy.

I can not figure out how to get this to work, for the result of my CASE statement or why it is only doing it for the CASE statement results and working find if a CASE statement is not involved. Any information you can provide would be helpful! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your column is being converted to text due to the `ELSE ''`. Because the blank `''` is actually text, it's converting the dates to text.

If you convert this to a date in SSRS using `=CDATE(Fields!DATE_FIELD.Value)`, your FORMAT function or property should work correctly.

You could also change your `ELSE ''` to `ELSE NULL` and the field **should** be recognized as DATE/TIME in SSRS.